# Electron focus app to trigger keyboard shortcuts

Tags: electron

When the app is not focused and is minimized I want to bring the app to the front and use keyboard shortcuts that is defined in renderer process (using JS).

I'm using this code in main process:

```
// here is inside a event handler to bring app on top
if (win.isMinimized()) win.restore();
win.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
app.focus();
win.show(); 
win.focus();

win.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
```

This makes the app in front of other apps but registered keyboard shortcuts won't work untill click mouse to focus the window. So I want to focus without mouse click.

Comment: Have you tried `win.focus()`?  You can also try `win.show()`

Comment: @Timur Yes, but no success. I updated the code in my question.